# Error MSB6006 "MakeAppx.exe" Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets debugging Visual Studio Cordova app on Windows Phone Device

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, windows-phone, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I'm facing a problem when I'm trying to test a Cordova App in my Windows Phone.

First, my configuration:

- Windows 8 Enterprise 64
- Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, logged in with my Microsoft account
- Windows 8.1 SKD
- Application developed with Cordova, Ionic Framework
- Windows Phone 8 (Nokia Lumia 625)

I'm able to run the application in an emulator, but when I'm trying to debugging my application on my Windows Phone, I got this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   MSB6006 "MakeAppx.exe" exited with code 1. [C:\Projects\Tests\BlankCordovaApp6\BlankCordovaApp6\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Phone.jsproj]  BlankCordovaApp6
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets   2439

I've setted the build output to detailed, and got this log:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2439,5): error MSB6006: "MakeAppx.exe" exited with code 1. [C:\Projetos\Testes\BlankCordovaApp6\BlankCordovaApp6\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Phone.jsproj]
>   1>MDAVSCLI : error : Error code 1 for command: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild with args: C:\Projetos\Testes\BlankCordovaApp6\BlankCordovaApp6\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Phone.jsproj,/clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;Verbosity=minimal,/nologo,/p:Configuration=debug,/p:Platform=arm
>   1>         Command finished with error code 2: cmd /s /c "C:\Projects\Tests\BlankCordovaApp6\BlankCordovaApp6\platforms\windows\cordova\build.bat --debug --archs=arm --phone --buildConfig=C:\Projects\Tests\BlankCordovaApp6\BlankCordovaApp6\build.json"
>   1>ERROR building one of the platforms : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
>   1>         You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
>   1>MDAVSCLI : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
>   1>       Done executing task "MdaVsCli" -- FAILED.

After read this log, I reinstaled the SDK after noticed this line **You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project**, but no success

I've also tried to run with this command line, but same error:

> cordova run --debug windows --device  -- --phone --appx=8.1-phone

I've followed the steps here, but no success too:
https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-windows-phone/

Any help and suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Following the @rido, I've tried to create a Windows Store App.

My VS2105 doesn't have this template, so I've installed. After created a empty Store App, Visual Studio asked to update my Microsoft Developer Licence.

Then, when I tried to build, I got an error noticing I was missing some platform requirements.

Looking for a solution, I followed the steps in this link: http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/

After updated VS2015 Cordova, I was able to deploy for Android and Windows Phone but prior I had to register my Windows Phone for development, following this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/apps/ff769508(v=vs.105).aspx

I hope these notes can help anyone else that has similar issues.

Comment: Can you confirm if your OS is Win8.0 or Win8.1? In case it's Win8.0.. can you try to create a Blank JS Windows Store app to see if your tooling works?

Comment: @rido, thank for your comment. My OS is Win 8.0, I'll try as you suggested and post the result.

Comment: @rido, I got, please read the update. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the steps in this link, but no success: http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/

After updated VS2015 Cordova, I was able to deploy for Android and Windows Phone but prior I had to register my Windows Phone for development, following this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/apps/ff769508(v=vs.105).aspx

Hope this can help anyone with similar issue.